# Use Getter Method and Return "0" in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, getter-setter, getter

I have created 2 classes and have used getter method. When I use the getter, its returning 0 all the time.

> **This is my fragment and try to get ColumnCount using Toast**

```
public class TimeTableFragment extends Fragment {

public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_timetable, container, false);

    TimetableView timetableView1 = new TimetableView(Objects
                                    .requireNonNull(getActivity()).getApplicationContext());
    timetableView1.findViewById(R.id.timetable_in_fragment);
    int num = timetableView1.getColumnCount();
    Toast.makeText(getContext(),""+num,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return root;
}}
```

> **This is TimetableView class that has setter and getter functions**

```
public class TimetableView extends LinearLayout {
private static final int DEFAULT_ROW_COUNT = 12;
private static final int DEFAULT_COLUMN_COUNT = 6;
private static final int DEFAULT_CELL_HEIGHT_DP = 50;
private static final int DEFAULT_SIDE_CELL_WIDTH_DP = 30;
private static final int DEFAULT_START_TIME = 9;

private static final int DEFAULT_SIDE_HEADER_FONT_SIZE_DP = 13;
private static final int DEFAULT_HEADER_FONT_SIZE_DP = 15;
private static final int DEFAULT_HEADER_HIGHLIGHT_FONT_SIZE_DP = 15;
private static final int DEFAULT_STICKER_FONT_SIZE_DP = 13;


private int rowCount;
private int columnCount;
private int cellHeight;
private int sideCellWidth;
private String[] headerTitle;
private String[] stickerColors;
private int startTime;
private int headerHighlightColor;

private RelativeLayout stickerBox;
TableLayout tableHeader;
TableLayout tableBox;

private Context context;

@SuppressLint("UseSparseArrays")
HashMap<Integer, Sticker> stickers = new HashMap<Integer, Sticker>();
private int stickerCount = -1;

private OnStickerSelectedListener stickerSelectedListener = null;

private HighlightMode highlightMode = HighlightMode.COLOR;
private int headerHighlightImageSize;
private Drawable headerHighlightImage = null;

public TimetableView(Context context) {
    super(context, null);
    this.context = context;
}

public TimetableView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public TimetableView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    this.context = context;
    getAttrs(attrs);
    init();
}

private void getAttrs(AttributeSet attrs) {
    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.TimetableView);
    rowCount = a.getInt(R.styleable.TimetableView_row_count, DEFAULT_ROW_COUNT) - 1;
    columnCount = a.getInt(R.styleable.TimetableView_column_count, DEFAULT_COLUMN_COUNT);
    cellHeight = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.TimetableView_cell_height, dp2Px(DEFAULT_CELL_HEIGHT_DP));
    sideCellWidth = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.TimetableView_side_cell_width, dp2Px(DEFAULT_SIDE_CELL_WIDTH_DP));
    int titlesId = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.TimetableView_header_title, R.array.default_header_title);
    headerTitle = a.getResources().getStringArray(titlesId);
    int colorsId = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.TimetableView_sticker_colors, R.array.default_sticker_color);
    stickerColors = a.getResources().getStringArray(colorsId);
    startTime = a.getInt(R.styleable.TimetableView_start_time, DEFAULT_START_TIME);
    headerHighlightColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.TimetableView_header_highlight_color, getResources().getColor(R.color.default_header_highlight_color));
    int highlightTypeValue = a.getInteger(R.styleable.TimetableView_header_highlight_type,0);
    if(highlightTypeValue == 0) highlightMode = HighlightMode.COLOR;
    else if(highlightTypeValue == 1) highlightMode = HighlightMode.IMAGE;
    headerHighlightImageSize = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.TimetableView_header_highlight_image_size, dp2Px(24));
    headerHighlightImage = a.getDrawable(R.styleable.TimetableView_header_highlight_image);
    a.recycle();
}

private void init() {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.view_timetable, this, false);
    addView(view);

    stickerBox = view.findViewById(R.id.sticker_box);
    tableHeader = view.findViewById(R.id.table_header);
    tableBox = view.findViewById(R.id.table_box);

    createTable();
}

public void setOnStickerSelectEventListener(OnStickerSelectedListener listener) {
    stickerSelectedListener = listener;
}

/**
 * date : 2019-02-08
 * get all schedules TimetableView has.
 */
public ArrayList<Schedule> getAllSchedulesInStickers() {
    ArrayList<Schedule> allSchedules = new ArrayList<Schedule>();
    for (int key : stickers.keySet()) {
        for (Schedule schedule : stickers.get(key).getSchedules()) {
            allSchedules.add(schedule);
        }
    }
    return allSchedules;
}

/**
 * date : 2019-02-08
 * Used in Edit mode, To check a invalidate schedule.
 */
public ArrayList<Schedule> getAllSchedulesInStickersExceptIdx(int idx) {
    ArrayList<Schedule> allSchedules = new ArrayList<Schedule>();
    for (int key : stickers.keySet()) {
        if (idx == key) continue;
        for (Schedule schedule : stickers.get(key).getSchedules()) {
            allSchedules.add(schedule);
        }
    }
    return allSchedules;
}

public void add(ArrayList<Schedule> schedules) {
    add(schedules, -1);
}

private void add(final ArrayList<Schedule> schedules, int specIdx) {
    final int count = specIdx < 0 ? ++stickerCount : specIdx;
    Sticker sticker = new Sticker();
    for (Schedule schedule : schedules) {
        TextView tv = new TextView(context);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams param = createStickerParam(schedule);
        tv.setLayoutParams(param);
        tv.setPadding(10, 0, 10, 0);
        tv.setText(schedule.getClassTitle() + "\n" + schedule.getClassPlace());
        tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
        tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, DEFAULT_STICKER_FONT_SIZE_DP);
        tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);

        tv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(stickerSelectedListener != null)
                    stickerSelectedListener.OnStickerSelected(count, schedules);
            }
        });

        sticker.addTextView(tv);
        sticker.addSchedule(schedule);
        stickers.put(count, sticker);
        stickerBox.addView(tv);
    }
    setStickerColor();
}

public String createSaveData() {
    return SaveManager.saveSticker(stickers);
}

public void load(String data) {
    removeAll();
    stickers = SaveManager.loadSticker(data);
    int maxKey = 0;
    for (int key : stickers.keySet()) {
        ArrayList<Schedule> schedules = stickers.get(key).getSchedules();
        add(schedules, key);
        if (maxKey < key) maxKey = key;
    }
    stickerCount = maxKey + 1;
    setStickerColor();
}

public void removeAll() {
    for (int key : stickers.keySet()) {
        Sticker sticker = stickers.get(key);
        for (TextView tv : sticker.getView()) {
            stickerBox.removeView(tv);
        }
    }
    stickers.clear();
}

public void edit(int idx, ArrayList<Schedule> schedules) {
    remove(idx);
    add(schedules, idx);
}

public void remove(int idx) {
    Sticker sticker = stickers.get(idx);
    for (TextView tv : sticker.getView()) {
        stickerBox.removeView(tv);
    }
    stickers.remove(idx);
    setStickerColor();
}

public void setHeaderHighlight(int idx) {
    if(idx < 0)return;
    TableRow row = (TableRow) tableHeader.getChildAt(0);
    View element = row.getChildAt(idx);
    if(highlightMode == HighlightMode.COLOR) {
        TextView tx = (TextView)element;
        tx.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
        tx.setBackgroundColor(headerHighlightColor);
        tx.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        tx.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, DEFAULT_HEADER_HIGHLIGHT_FONT_SIZE_DP);
    }
    else if(highlightMode == HighlightMode.IMAGE){
        RelativeLayout outer = new RelativeLayout(context);
        outer.setLayoutParams(createTableRowParam(cellHeight));
        ImageView iv = new ImageView(context);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(headerHighlightImageSize,headerHighlightImageSize);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT,RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        iv.setLayoutParams(params);
        iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

        row.removeViewAt(idx);
        outer.addView(iv);
        row.addView(outer,idx);

        if(headerHighlightImage != null) {
            iv.setImageDrawable(headerHighlightImage);
        }

    }
}

private void setStickerColor() {
    int size = stickers.size();
    int[] orders = new int[size];
    int i = 0;
    for (int key : stickers.keySet()) {
        orders[i++] = key;
    }
    Arrays.sort(orders);

    int colorSize = stickerColors.length;

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (TextView v : stickers.get(orders[i]).getView()) {
            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(stickerColors[i % (colorSize)]));
        }
    }

}

private void createTable() {
    createTableHeader();
    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
        TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(context);
        tableRow.setLayoutParams(createTableLayoutParam());

        for (int k = 0; k < columnCount; k++) {
            TextView tv = new TextView(context);
            tv.setLayoutParams(createTableRowParam(cellHeight));
            if (k == 0) {
                tv.setText(getHeaderTime(i));
                tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorHeaderText));
                tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, DEFAULT_SIDE_HEADER_FONT_SIZE_DP);
                tv.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorHeader));
                tv.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                tv.setLayoutParams(createTableRowParam(sideCellWidth, cellHeight));
            } else {
                tv.setText("");
                tv.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.item_border));
                tv.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
            }
            tableRow.addView(tv);
        }
        tableBox.addView(tableRow);
    }
}

private void createTableHeader() {
    TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(context);
    tableRow.setLayoutParams(createTableLayoutParam());

    for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
        TextView tv = new TextView(context);
        if (i == 0) {
            tv.setLayoutParams(createTableRowParam(sideCellWidth, cellHeight));
        } else {
            tv.setLayoutParams(createTableRowParam(cellHeight));
        }
        tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorHeaderText));
        tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, DEFAULT_HEADER_FONT_SIZE_DP);
        tv.setText(headerTitle[i]);
        tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        tableRow.addView(tv);
    }
    tableHeader.addView(tableRow);
}

private RelativeLayout.LayoutParams createStickerParam(Schedule schedule) {
    int cell_w = calCellWidth();

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams param = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(cell_w, calStickerHeightPx(schedule));
    param.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    param.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
    param.setMargins(sideCellWidth + cell_w * schedule.getDay(), calStickerTopPxByTime(schedule.getStartTime()), 0, 0);

    return param;
}

private int calCellWidth(){
    Display display = ((Activity) context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int cell_w = (size.x-getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight()- sideCellWidth) / (columnCount - 1);
    return cell_w;
}

private int calStickerHeightPx(Schedule schedule) {
    int startTopPx = calStickerTopPxByTime(schedule.getStartTime());
    int endTopPx = calStickerTopPxByTime(schedule.getEndTime());
    int d = endTopPx - startTopPx;

    return d;
}

private int calStickerTopPxByTime(Time time) {
    int topPx = (time.getHour() - startTime) * cellHeight + (int) ((time.getMinute() / 60.0f) * cellHeight);
    return topPx;
}

private TableLayout.LayoutParams createTableLayoutParam() {
    return new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
}

private TableRow.LayoutParams createTableRowParam(int h_px) {
    return new TableRow.LayoutParams(calCellWidth(), h_px);
}

private TableRow.LayoutParams createTableRowParam(int w_px, int h_px) {
    return new TableRow.LayoutParams(w_px, h_px);
}

private String getHeaderTime(int i) {
    int p = (startTime + i) % 24;
    int res = p <= 12 ? p : p - 12;
    return res + "";
}

static private int dp2Px(int dp) {
    return (int) (dp * Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density);
}

private void onCreateByBuilder(Builder builder) {
    this.rowCount = builder.rowCount;
    this.columnCount = builder.columnCount;
    this.cellHeight = builder.cellHeight;
    this.sideCellWidth = builder.sideCellWidth;
    this.headerTitle = builder.headerTitle;
    this.stickerColors = builder.stickerColors;
    this.startTime = builder.startTime;
    this.headerHighlightColor = builder.headerHighlightColor;

    init();
}

public int getRowCount() {
    return rowCount;
}

public void setRowCount(int rowCount) {
    this.rowCount = rowCount;
}

public int getColumnCount() {
    return columnCount;
}

public void setColumnCount(int columnCount) {
    this.columnCount = columnCount;
}


public interface OnStickerSelectedListener {
    void OnStickerSelected(int idx, ArrayList<Schedule> schedules);
}

public static class Builder {
    private Context context;
    private int rowCount;
    private int columnCount;
    private int cellHeight;
    private int sideCellWidth;
    private String[] headerTitle;
    private String[] stickerColors;
    private int startTime;
    private int headerHighlightColor;

    public Builder(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        rowCount = DEFAULT_ROW_COUNT;
        columnCount = DEFAULT_COLUMN_COUNT;
        cellHeight = dp2Px(DEFAULT_CELL_HEIGHT_DP);
        sideCellWidth = dp2Px(DEFAULT_SIDE_CELL_WIDTH_DP);
        headerTitle = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.default_header_title);
        stickerColors = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.default_sticker_color);
        startTime = DEFAULT_START_TIME;
        headerHighlightColor = context.getResources().getColor(R.color.default_header_highlight_color);
    }

    public Builder setRowCount(int n) {
        this.rowCount = n;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder setColumnCount(int n) {
        this.columnCount = n;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder setCellHeight(int dp) {
        this.cellHeight = dp2Px(dp);
        return this;
    }

    public Builder setSideCellWidth(int dp) {
        this.sideCellWidth = dp2Px(dp);
        return this;
    }

    public Builder setHeaderTitle(String[] titles) {
        this.headerTitle = titles;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder setStickerColors(String[] colors) {
        this.stickerColors = colors;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder setStartTime(int t) {
        this.startTime = t;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder setHeaderHighlightColor(int c) {
        this.headerHighlightColor = c;
        return this;
    }

    public TimetableView build() {
        TimetableView timetableView = new TimetableView(context);
        timetableView.onCreateByBuilder(this);
        return timetableView;
    }
}}
```

If you have any suggestions that reason why it's returned always 0, Please let me know. 
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You aren't setting it in the constructor.  Your Builder code isn't used here, you're creating the View directly via new.  So column count is never set to a default, thus it's initialized to 0 like all unset member variables.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there any methods to use get column count after using findViewById? I thought I should have the number that I have declared in layout xml file.

Comment: Your code isn't right for that.  You're not getting the view from your layout.  You're creating a new one.  Then you're looking inside that for another timetable view.  What you want is to delete both the line where you new and the line where you do a find and replace it with TimetableView timetableView = findViewById(R.id.timetable_in_fragment);

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand your point and problem is if I replace as TimetableView timetableView = findViewById, then I got null exception error when  I tried to use timetableView.getrowCount.

Comment: Sorry, it should be root.findViewById.  My mistake.  You want to look for the view in the layout you inflated.

Answer (score 0):

U need to set the value of columnCount whether in the constructor or in the setter to avoid returning 0 in the getter.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there any methods to use get column count after using findViewById?I thought I should have the number that I have declared in layout xml file.

Comment: Sorry but I did not get u, please try to make it more clear

Comment: Thank you very much and, I am trying to use getColumnCount after declared TimetableView timetableView = findViewById(R.id.timetable_in_fragment); , however I got null exception error when I tried it